# EKEvent created and removed if endDate changed

Tags: ios, calendar

The following code works, no problem at all.

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()

                eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event, completion: { (granted, error) in

                    if granted == false { return }

                    let e = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                    e.title = self.event!.title

                    let meh = self.event!.commencement
                    print("\(meh)")
                    e.startDate = meh

                    e.location = self.event!.venue.contact.address.assembleAddress()

                    let bleh = NSDate(timeInterval: Double(60*24*60*60), sinceDate: self.event!.commencement)
                    print("\(bleh)")
                    e.endDate = bleh

                    e.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                    e.URL = self.event!.marketingURL
                    e.addAlarm(EKAlarm(absoluteDate: self.event!.commencement.dateByAddingTimeInterval(Double(-60*60*24*7))))

                    do {
                        try eventStore.saveEvent(e, span: .ThisEvent, commit: true)
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("error \(error)")
                    }

                })
```

When I change the end date to 8 hours ahead of the commence date, the event is not created, or for a fleeting moment it is there, then the network activity indicator spins and it is removed.

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()

                eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event, completion: { (granted, error) in

                    if granted == false { return }

                    let e = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                    e.title = self.event!.title

                    let meh = self.event!.commencement
                    print("\(meh)")
                    e.startDate = meh

                    e.location = self.event!.venue.contact.address.assembleAddress()

                    let bleh = NSDate(timeInterval: Double(8*60*60), sinceDate: self.event!.commencement)
                    print("\(bleh)")
                    e.endDate = bleh

                    e.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
                    e.URL = self.event!.marketingURL
                    e.addAlarm(EKAlarm(absoluteDate: self.event!.commencement.dateByAddingTimeInterval(Double(-60*60*24*7))))

                    do {
                        try eventStore.saveEvent(e, span: .ThisEvent, commit: true)
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("error \(error)")
                    }

                })
```

No error is printed. What's going on ?

Answer (score 0):

The date is in the past. Make sure the date is in the future.